# spring boot postconstruct not called when running java -jar

Tags: spring-boot

I have the following class which has postconstruct.. But it doesnt seem to call the postconstruct? But it works in the eclipse IDE? But when i call it via java -jar... nothing

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }   
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void postcontruct()  {
               System.out.println("******************TEST ********");
    }

}
```

Comment: The `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class itself is not a managed bean (`@Component`, `@Bean`, `@Configuration` etc) - `@PostConstruct` only works on managed beans :)

Comment: I might be... Because no classes are instantiated at all! Your `main` method is in a static method that do not requires an `Application` instance to be created (that would implies the call of the `postconstruct` method.

Comment: @roookeee But it works in the IDE, so i guess it workes slightly different in the IDE?

Comment: It shouldn't work from the IDE either, are you using Eclipse by chance?